# How to remove the white background in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a `background` image to my `tableview`. But when i pull the `scroll` down i see a `white` `background`. How can get rid of this ?

Comment: How exactly did you add a background image? Programmatically? In Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, programmatically. i used `colorWithPatternImage` to set the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can make it very simple :

> 1. use a image with the same size as table view have and put it on the back side of tableview.
> 2. than set table view background color clear

```
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to have your problem when I set the background like so in my **MasterViewController.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing as TDeBailleul throughout an app and still had one UITableView remain white.

To fix this, I went through a bunch of things to make sure nothing collided with the background, including setting the cells' backgrounds to clear, setting the table view's background to Default in Interface Builder.

Just go around Interface Builder and your code to make sure nothing is set that would change the background of either the table view or the cells.

I think what finally did it for me was programmatically setting the background at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

On the Attribute Inspector, with the tableview selected, there are three sections:

- Table view
- Scroll view
- View

The View section has a "background" attribute that will determine what's seen when scrolling. 
Hope this helps :-)